# Display shopping cart only when salable products are displayed

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, shopping-cart

In Magento 2 I want to be able to display the shopping cart (e.g. minicart) in the header of the shop only when products are displayed on the page that are salable. The shop I'm building has two types of products:

- Products that are displayed as informative products (as a catalogue without purchase ability).
- Products that should be purchased.

The last one will only be displayed in one (or maybe two) categories.

Comment: can you please share more info (with link)

Answer (score 1):

For this first you need to create one product attribute like Salebale with `Yes/No` value

then need to add condition on minicart.phtml

> app/design/frontend/Yourpackage/Yourtheme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

Here First you need to get current product as you need to hide minicart from product page so to get current product use below code

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
echo $product->getId();
echo $product->getName();
?>
```

Or Add bellow code in your block file.
for example

> app/code/Packagename/Modulename/Block/CustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace Packagename\Modulename\Block;
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,       
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {       
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }   
}
?>
```

Printing current product data in your template (custom.phtml) file

```
if ($currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct()) {
    echo $currentProduct->getName() . '<br />';    
}
```

So when you get the current product object then get saleable attribute value using current product like below

```
<?php $saleable = $currentProduct->getSalebale(); ?>
```

then in above mentioned minicart.phtml add condition to show minicart only on Saleable product page.
put all minicart code in condition like

```
<?php if($saleable): ?>
/******* Minicart content **********/
<?php endif; ?>
```